# How do I read/write to a subgroup withing a HDF5Store?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I am using the HDF5Store, to store some of my processed results, prior to analysis.
Into the store I want to put 3 types of results,

- Raw results, that have not been processed at all, just read-in and merged from their original CSV formats
- Processed results that are derived from the raw results, that have some proccessing and division into more logical groupings
- Summarised results that have useful summery columns added and redundant columns removed, for easy reading.

I thought a HDF5Store with Hierarchical Keys would do it, one for Raw, one for Processed and one for Summarised.

I wanted a structure like:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: results.h5
/proccessed/dbn_reinit                           frame        (shape->[22880,19])
/proccessed/dbn_rerep_code                       frame        (shape->[11440,18])
/proccessed/dbn_rerep_enhanced_input             frame        (shape->[11440,18])
/proccessed/linear_classifier                    frame        (shape->[572,18])  
/proccessed/msda_rerep_code                      frame        (shape->[18304,17])
/proccessed/msda_rerep_enhanced_input            frame        (shape->[18304,17])
/raw/dbn_reinit                                  frame        (shape->[22880,15])
/raw/dbn_rerep                                   frame        (shape->[23452,15])
/raw/msda_rerep                                  frame        (shape->[36608,14])
/summerised/dbn_reinit                           frame        (shape->[22880,10])
/summerised/dbn_rerep_code                       frame        (shape->[11440,9]) 
/summerised/dbn_rerep_enhanced_input             frame        (shape->[11440,9]) 
/summerised/linear_classifier                    frame        (shape->[572,6])   
/summerised/msda_rerep_code                      frame        (shape->[18304,10])
/summerised/msda_rerep_enhanced_input            frame        (shape->[18304,10])
```

I expected I could create this by saying:

```
store = pandas.HDF5Store('results.h5')
store.add_group('raw')
raw_store = store['raw'] 
raw_store['dbn_reinit'] = dbn_reinit_dataframe
raw_store['dbn_rerep_code'] = dbn_rerep_code_dataframe
...
```

etc

However there doesn't seem to be a method of getting a subgroup of a store and using it as it it was a store,

so i had to do:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('results.h5', mode='w')

store['raw/dbn_reinit'] = dbn_reinit_dataframe
store['raw/dbn_rerep'] = dbn_reinit_dataframe
...
```

which is wordy, and doesn't really show any kind of grouping of the results into the 3 catagories
Am i missing something?
Or is the Hieratrchical features of the HDF, 
just writing really long key names that have `/`s in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docs on using the hierarchical keys are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hierarchical-keys). `.remove()` has this type of functionaility, where you can remove nodes at that level and further down the tree.

You can do: `store.get_storer('foo')` to return an object that includes access to the node. (e.g. `.group`). However, this object won't  allow you to add/select sub-nodes, nor does it provide a nice repr of that node.

You could put in a feature request for these features on github. Please include a reproducible example of what you think this should do.

Pull-requests are welcome!

I rarely use multiple groups. Mainly because of the flexibility of using different files. You can do what you are trying to do, I just have never found a need for it (e.g. treat your group as the file itself). HDF5 is not a database so this is rarely useful